Standards in e-bike electrics
The research I've undertaken seems to lead to this statement, "There are no standards in e-bike controller wiring", it's a free for all! My question is: Is there any organization pushing for standards in wiring? If so, who are they?

Related question: https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/89359/what-characterizes-a-future-proof-ebike-drive-system

It is rare for standards to be driven from outside the industry; as long as the current scheme works for existing manufacturers, no sufficiently capitalized new entrant arises to compete with them, and the repair process is divorced from new sales (so there is no unified force pushing for standardized or competitively source spare parts) there's no reason to expect standards to be developed.

Like most industries it take a few years of maturity, but it will come. For instance, https://www.oshwa.org/ the open source hardware association are likely to talk about the Electric bike industry in their upcoming summit in Montreal. Already we are seeing UL (and possibly CSA in Canada) getting into the game by certifying controllers, batteries and frames for safety standards.  This forces basic standards. Time will tell. Chinese wiring manufacturers are already talking about standards in pin-outs on harnesses so it looks promising.
